# cant tint my boostrap 4 carousel images

Tags: html, css, image, colors, bootstrap-4

trying to add an image tint to my carousel images (BS4), my initial understanding was to use

```
.tinted-image img {
  background: 
    /* top, transparent red */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),
}
```

codepen link - https://codepen.io/nightcoder21/pen/RyeYoz

this dosent seem to work, does anyone know any easy way to do this? (im trying to keep my code as simple and clutter free as possible)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css into this

```
.tinted-image:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
     rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
     rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
  );
}
```

you can check it here : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvqZvK

By using :before selector you can tint images with different colors ^^

Comment: thanks,that worked perfectly in my codepen,however the images are simply URL links..in my real project im using locally stored images,when i copy and paste in your above, nothing happens?..any idea?

Comment: can you put some code? I already try using locally stored images and it looks fine.. i'm not sure either lol
And also make sure you put all the image into div class "tinted-image"

Comment: that image with a dog has a nice blue/greenish tint,how can i apply that to my pic? codepen link https://codepen.io/nightcoder21/pen/yjRRKZ

Comment: change background to : background: rgba(0,255,255, 0.5);

Comment: sorry im spiining my tyres here and getting no where..here is the latest codepen https://codepen.io/nightcoder21/pen/yjRRKZ,it seems like whatever color i set is not applying

Comment: you forget to put "." on your css

Comment: fixed it  -https://codepen.io/nightcoder21/pen/yjRRKZ,still trying to understand how i get that image color of the dog in this codepen,i must be missing something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171217/discussion-between-beginnerprogrammer-and-ravi21).